# ">>=" operator and "map" function

Tags: haskell

I have a working code from the example of the openbrowser library.

```
import Web.Browser (openBrowser)
main :: IO ()
main = openBrowser "http://haskell.org/" >>= print
```

What I would like to do is to open two websites.

So I was think doing something like:

```
main = map openBrowser ["http://haskell.org/","http://google.com/"] >>= print
```

And I would get

```
Couldn't match type ‘[]’ with ‘IO’
Expected type: IO (IO Bool)
Actual type: [IO Bool]
```

But I have a very hard time figuring out what is the proper way to call this >>= print command if I use map.

Answer (score 4):

### using `forM`

In this case I would use [`forM_`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.2.0/docs/Control-Monad.html#v:forM):

```
main = 
    forM_ ["http://haskell.org/","http://google.com/"] (openBrowser >=> print)
```

which you can use to *repeat* an `a -> IO b` action for each item in an list `[a]` and get an `IO ()` (the result of the action will be discarded - with the `forM_` version which is what we want as it should be our `main` so it has to be `IO ()` - the `forM` version would yield `IO [()]` instead)

### using `mapM`

or if you want to stick closer to your idea you can use `map` [`mapM_`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.2.0/docs/Control-Monad.html#v:mapM) instead:

```
main = 
    mapM_ (openBrowser >=> print) ["http://haskell.org/","http://google.com/"]
```

which is just `forM_` with the arguments flipped - the type-explanation is just the same.

### using `sequence`

the reason yours does not work is that `openBrowswer` will return an `IO Bool` action (or so it seems based on the error message) and so the `map` will return an `[IO Bool]` but to use `(>>=)` you need some `IO a`

So you would need to first *collapse* the list into one `IO` action (which can be done with [`sequence :: [IO a] -> IO [a]`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.2.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:sequence)):

```
main = 
    sequence (map openBrowser ["http://haskell.org/","http://google.com/"]) >>= print
```

which should print an list `[True, True]` hopefully

---

But I think what you really wanted to do is to open the site and print the result *for each* (on a newline without the list brackets)

Comment: @dfeuer yes I do ... happens do me all the time when I cannot check/compile my answers - sorry